# AngularJS - Keep file selected even if it was hidden via an ng-if

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a little script that can hide or show some divs. Each div will contain a file input.

My problem is that when the div is hidden, the selected file is gone, why is that so ?

Here's an example (http://jsfiddle.net/etiennenoel/8k4M7/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.13" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>


    <div ng-if="test == true">
      <input type="file">
    </div>
    <button ng-click="test = !test">test</button>

  </body>

</html>
```

First, you must click on the test button.

Second, you select a file.

Third, you click on the test button twice.

You'll see that the selected file is now gone, why ? Do I really have to create a directive for this ? Meaning that I would save the file somewhere ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The selected file is gone because if the condition of `ng-if` evaluates to `false`, all contents of the element are removed from the DOM. When the condition is `true` the content is reinserted and therefore loses its previous state.

You could use `ng-show`. It doesn't remove the contents from the DOM.

Here is the fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/3fgLx/**